# Get a value in the same row as another item (SQL)

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following table:

| key1 | key2 | key3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1.1 | val1.2 | val1.3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| valN.1 | valN.2 | valN.3 |

How can I get the value of `valN.2` knowing only `valN.1`?
`valN.1` is the only instance of that value in `key1`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select key2 
from input_table
Where key1='valN.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that the first column is unique, then a simple SELECT will do:

```
SELECT Key2 FROM YourTable WHERE Key1 = 'valN.1'
```